# Filter a list based on a dropdown choice that matches an object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items (li element using ng-repeat) on my page and a dropdown menu (select element using ng-options). When the dropdown selection matches a particular property on the items I only want those matched items to show.

The list item objects look like this:

```
var foo = {
    someProperty: 'someValue',
    someOtherProperty: 'someOtherValue',
    items: [{
        propertyIWantToMatchOn: 'someImportantValue', /* Note that there will be a lot of items, but they all contain this property */
        someDisplayText: 'this can be arbitrary'
    }]
};
```

Sometimes the list items will have a `propertyIWantToMatchOn` value of `someImportantValue`and sometimes they will have a value of `someOtherImportantValue`.

My list of choices looks like this:

```
var myChoices = [
    {name: 'someImportantValue'},
    {name: 'someOtherImportantValue'}
];
```

My select dropdown looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedChoice" ng-options="myChoice.name for myChoice in myChoices"></select>
```

My list items are being generated as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in foo.items | filter:{propertyIWantToMatchOn: mySelectedChoice}">{{item.someDisplayText}}</li>
</ul>
```

With the current filter, nothing shows up in my list regardless of choice that is selected. If I remove the filter, all of the items show regardless of what is selected.

How do I modify the filter/my code so that I can only show the items whose property matches the selection from the dropdown?

Cheers!

edit: If I hardcode `mySelectedChoice` in my controller to be a string that matches the property value that I'm trying to match on, the list filters correctly. So I guess now I need to work out how to save choices as the value of `name` rather than the object itself.

Comment: What you want to show inside the ng-repeat? Based on propertyIWantToMatchOn what you want to list? Does items has only "propertyIWantToMatchOn" ? Give an example of expected output.

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that. It's actually irrelevant what I want to be displaying, I just want the item display text to show for all the items whose property matches the dropdown selection :) I have updated my code to include what I want to display.

Comment: My solution solves the problem of saving name as object.You can use ng-option to update the name in ngmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-option` with `as` so that you can update the `name` in `ng-model`.Then use the `ng-model` of list in the filtered condition of `ng-repeat`.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/618/)

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedChoice" ng-options="myChoice.name as myChoice.name for myChoice in myChoices"></select> 

 selceted value is {{mySelectedChoice}}

 <ul ng-show="mySelectedChoice">
      <li ng-repeat="item in foo.items | filter:{propertyIWantToMatchOn: mySelectedChoice}">{{item.someDisplayText}}</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Yep the `as` option was what I was looking for! Your code example illustrated it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own problem. Only a slight choice was required!

In my `<li>` markup I just needed to change `filter:{propertyIWantToMatchOn: mySelectedChoice}` to `filter:{propertyIWantToMatchOn: mySelectedChoice.name}`

Thanks guys!